# Pyspark - create training set and testing set from dataframe

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe like the photo below. I would like to create a training and testing set out of it. The dataset is ordered by CustomerID and InvoiceNo. For each customer, I would like to take every row except the last 2 rows of that customer as training set, while the second to the last row of each customer would become a training set.

The result would be ideally 1 giant training set and 1 testing set. Is there an efficient way to do that with PySpark? Thanks a lot for your help in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always add an index and filter based off of that index--not sure if there's anything more efficient than that.

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as func

window = Window.partitionBy(func.col("CustomerID"))\
        .orderBy(func.col("InvoiceNo").desc())
df = df.select('*', func.rank().over(window).alias('rank'))

train = df.filter("rank > 2")
test = df.filter("rank <= 2")
```